# API Operations for Modifying Quantity or Removing Products from Cart in [https\\:exapmlesitewordpress.ma]

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I'm currently facing challenges while working on integration with [Your E-commerce Platform]. My goal is to modify the quantity of a product in the cart or delete a product from the cart using the platform's API or URL requests.

Here's the code snippet I'm using in PHP with cURL to add products to the cart:

```php
function addToCart($productId, $token , $quantity) {
    $your_domain = 'https://exemple.ma/';
    $cart_url = $your_domain . 'cart/?add-to-cart=' . $productId . '&quantity=' . $quantity; // URL to add product to cart with quantity
    $ch = curl_init($cart_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
    ]);
    $cart_response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $cart_response;
}

// Authenticate and obtain the token
$token = "MY TOKEN";
if ($token) {
    $productId = 1008421;
    $quantity = 1;
    $cartResponse = addToCart($productId, $token , $quantity);
} else {
    echo 'Authentication failed.';
}
```

Comment: Pardon me but your question is not clear. (At least to me, it's not.) I assume there is a problem with the code you posted, however I don't think you explained what that problem is. Or are you asking for someone to show you how to delete a product from the cart?